# Spring DirtyContext is bad

Tags: spring, spring-test

I don't understand why there is only one option provided by Spring when context is dirty in tests.
During tests, if there are few beans dirty then why can't we recreate those beans instead of shutting down the entire context and loading it again. It should have some way to reset the context i.e reset the beans which are dirty not the entire context.

Because an application comprises of connections to external resources which would be time-consuming operation when you recreate after every time dirty context listener is executed. 
If 1 beans is dirty then why to reinitialize the entire context. Spring team needs to revisit this functionality and provide a sensible solution.

Comment: This is not a question, request a feature in the Springframework JIRA. What about the dependencies between beans used in beans used in beans? Dirty context offers the easiest stroke. You could always load your beans differently, or break down your configuration files to minimal required to only load what is required.

Comment: I thought of this , could be hard to achieve because of nested dependencies. When we write tests , we focus on one area and keep other area unchanged so thought something would be useful. I thought of adding extra configuration to narrow down the  area but it makes it hard to manage configuration just for tests because production deployment requires all component tied together. Anyways I will raise with Spring.